# What do I add across the opamp to get a full sine wave?

Tags: operational-amplifier, sine, saturation

I'm struggling to figure out a solution to avoid saturation, I believe the solution will require some component to be attached across the opamp to produce the same voltage out as voltage in (voltage in is a full sine wave).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try adding a negative power supply.

Comment: ... or a capacitor in series with both input and output, and biassing resistors to mid-rail to the amplifier + input.

Comment: In reality (as opposed to simulation) the output could  flat-line *permanently* after 2ms since you've greatly exceeded the absolute maximum input voltage limits of V+\$\ge\$ Vin \$\ge\$ V- .

Comment: If you want negative outputs from an op-amp, you need to power it with negative voltage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are powering the opamp with a single supply. This limits Vout to between 0-5V. Instead of connecting the negative supply pin to ground, connect it to -5V and Vout can now go between +/- 5V.